# NP-hardness of vertex cover for 3-chromatic graphs

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

Is the vertex cover problem remains NP-hard for 3-chromatic graphs?
I am almost certain it is, but was unable to find a reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is NP-hard via reduction to Independent Set in cubic (3-regular) graphs.
Cubic graphs different from $K_4$ are 3-colorable in polynomial time via Brooks' theorem and IS remains NP-hard for them.

For a reference, check [graphclasses.org](https://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_1100.html).